# Formatting large number to prevent scientific notation

Tags: excel, vba

I stored 100000000 to a cell from a textBox. The Value appears as 100000000  itself in the cell stored but when I Bring back the value to the textBox, it appears as 1E+08. How do I change this?

Update: I have worked around the problem by storing my values as strings and converting string into single later.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to retain it as a numeric value, you would need to format the cell it's in. If you put it in cell A1, then you would use:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "000000000"
```

To get it back into the textbox as displayed, use the `.Text` property instead of the `.Value` property.

```
txtNumber = Range("A1").Text
```

However, the `.Text` property just retrieves what you see in the cell, so if they cell is not wide enough to display the entire number it may display something like `#####` instead, in which case, that's what the `.Text` property will give you.

To deal with that, you can use the `AutoSize` method before retrieving the property:

```
Range("A1").Columns.AutoFit
```

or

```
Columns(1).Autofit
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Then you must not be doing both steps. You cannot do just one of them, you have to do them both. It works for everyone else... Try it in a completely blank workbook to first verify that it works, then figure out what else your code is doing that is causing it to not work.

Comment: I have worked around the problem by storing my values as strings and converting using string into single later.

Comment: I suppose if that's how you want it to work in your case... not really needed, but again... as long as it works I guess